# jQuery working with dropdown but not radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to rewrite this section of a jQuery script so that it is triggered by selection of a radio button and not a dropdown.

```
var check_engraving = $('#attrib-2');
if (check_engraving.val() == 4) {
enable_engraving = true;
$('#individual_engraving_wrapper').show();
```

The new radio button that needs to trigger it is:

```
<span class="EngraveAttribute4"><input type="radio" name="id[2]" value="540" id="attrib-2-540" /><label class="attribsRadioButton zero" for="attrib-2-540">I would like different engraving on each of these items</label><br /></span>
```

It's obviously no good changing it to

```
var check_engraving = $('#attrib-2-540');
if (check_engraving.val() == 540) {
```

as the value is always 540 regardless of whether or not it is selected.

I tried to use

```
$('input:radio[name="id[2]"]').change(function () {
if ($(this).val() == '540') {
enable_engraving = true;
$('#individual_engraving_wrapper').show();
}
});
```

which I thought was working ok, but if I update the quantity I have to deselect then reselect the radio button for engraving to be true. The old dropdown system stayed as true when the quantity was updated.

I'm sure this can be done, but I'm stumped on it. Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: use click  event on radio button

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$('input[type=radio][name="id[2]"]').change(function () {
if ($(this).val() == '540') {
enable_engraving = true;
$('#individual_engraving_wrapper').show();
}
});
```

Comment: Can you explain why that will function differently from the code i tried. I'm still learning at this and would like to have an understanding of how it differs.